# Interface is unable to use method even though they are of the same type

Tags: go

I have a stage issue. It looks completely correct to me but my IDE keeps showing me this error and will not compile.

```
Cannot use 'userRepo' (type *UserRepo) as the type UserRepository Type does not 
implement 'UserRepository' need the method: GetByEmail(email string) (*User, error) 
have the method: GetByEmail(email string) (*User, error)
```

UserRepository.go

```
type UserRepo struct {
    db         *mongo.Client
    collection *mongo.Collection
}


func (m *UserRepo) GetByEmail(email string) (*User, error) {

    ctx := context.Background()

    var user *User
    err := m.collection.FindOne(ctx, bson.M{"username": email}).Decode(&user)
    if err != nil {
        return &User{}, err
    }

    return user, nil
}

func NewUserRepository(client *mongo.Client, collection *mongo.Collection) *UserRepo {
    return &UserRepo{
        db:         client,
        collection: collection,
    }
}
```

LoginService.go

```
type Login struct {
    helper    pkg.Helper
    user      User
    res       LoginResponse
    repo      Repository
    userRepo  UserRepository
    tokenRepo TokenRepository
    cfg       config.Config
    validator *validator.Validator
}

type UserRepository interface {
    GetByEmail(email string) (*User, error)
}

func (l *Login) CreateAccountHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    
    .....

    _, err = l.userRepo.GetByEmail(email)
    // Check if the username is already taken.
    if err != nil {
        http.Error(w, "Username already taken", http.StatusConflict)

        json.NewEncoder(w).Encode(failedResponse)
        return
    }
}

func NewLoginService(repository Repository, tokenRepo TokenRepository, userRepo UserRepository) *Login {
    return &Login{
        helper:    pkg.Helper{},
        repo:      repository,
        userRepo:  userRepo,
        tokenRepo: tokenRepo,
        validator: validator.New(),
    }
}
```

The method names are the same and the type..

main.go

```
// Login
    loginCollection := client.Database(cfg.MongoConfig.DBName).Collection(cfg.MongoConfig.LoginCollection)
    loginRepo := login.NewLoginRepository(client, loginCollection)
    usersCollection := client.Database(cfg.MongoConfig.DBName).Collection(cfg.UsersConfig.UserCollection)
    userRepo := data.NewUserRepository(client, usersCollection)
    loginService := login.NewLoginService(loginRepo, tokenRepo, userRepo) <----- error is here "userRepo"
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on

```
userRepo := data.NewUserRepository(client, usersCollection)
loginService := login.NewLoginService(loginRepo, tokenRepo, userRepo)
```

`NewUserRepository` is in the package `data` so the `*User` in `GetByEmail(email string) (*User, error)` is a `data.User` whereas,

`NewLoginService` is in the package `login` so the `*User` in the `GetByEmail` within the `UserRepository` interface is a `login.User`.

`data.User` and `login.User` are different types hence the error. To correct this alter either the function or the interface such that the type returned is from the same package.